# Which qualifiers should I use for supporting my layouts for different phones screens?

Tags: android, screen, pixel, dpi

I have some problems with supporting my layouts for different phone/tablet screensizes. My layouts dosn't fit or scale on all screens probably. Some screen sizes give too much space and other dosn't have room for all views.

I have tried to generate different layouts with different qualifiers like: densities, dimensions and sizes in PX and with large/small/x-large qualifiers. 
But I can't really figure out what qualiferes I should use to completely fit all screens.

This is a description of how my layouts behave with different screens (tested with genymotion emulator)

**480px x 800px 240dpi** (S3 Mini): Views dosn't fit in heights.

**480px x 800px 120dpi**: (Emulator): Views dosn't fit in heights

**480px x 800px 320dpi:** Too much free space around the views.

**600px x 1024px 240dpi:** Perfect fit!

**600px x 1024px 420dpi:** There is almost no space to show anything. maybe 2-3 views at max

**1440px x 2560px 560dpi**: a little bit of free space

**1440px x 2560px 640DPI:** Perfect fit!

**1440px x 2560px 320DPI:** Too much free space around the views

Here is screenshots examples of how the layout **Stats** scale with different screens:

**Samsung S3 MINI: 480px x 800px 240dpi:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvxggql80ivcmlp/galaxys3mini.png?dl=0

**Samsung Galaxy S7: 1440px x 2560px 640DPI:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/ivjd6a0zgc81oqy/galaxys7.png?dl=0

**Nexus 9 API 23  2048x1536 xhdpi:**https://www.dropbox.com/s/r70h4da1xcf2lhi/nexus9.PNG?dl=0

What qualifiers should I use?'

The layouts xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/arion_darkblue">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stats_title"
    style="@style/fragment_titles_style"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Stats" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/statsgroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/stats_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stats_distance_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_stats_distance" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stats_distance_txt"
        style="@style/fragments_textstyles"
        android:layout_below="@id/stats_distance_img"
        android:text="0,0 Km" />

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/stats_jump_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stats_distance_txt"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_stats_jump" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stats_jump_txt"
        style="@style/fragments_textstyles"
        android:layout_below="@id/stats_distance_img"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stats_distance_txt"
        android:text="00" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stats_transition_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stats_jump_txt"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_stats_transition" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stats_transition_txt"
        style="@style/fragments_textstyles"
        android:layout_below="@id/stats_distance_img"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stats_jump_txt"
        android:text="00" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stats_intensity_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stats_transition_img"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_stats_intensity" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stats_intensity_txt"
        style="@style/fragments_textstyles"
        android:layout_below="@id/stats_distance_img"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stats_transition_txt"
        android:text="0000" />

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/stats_symmetric_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/statsgroup1"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stats_sym_txt1"
        style="@style/fragments_textstyles"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="50%" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stats_symmertic_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stats_sym_txt1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_stats_symmetric" />


    <TextView

        style="@style/fragments_textstyles"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stats_symmertic_img"
        android:text="50%" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stats_rotation_txt1"
            style="@style/fragments_textstyles"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="50%" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stats_rotation_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stats_rotation_txt1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_stats_rotation" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stats_rotation_txt2"
            style="@style/fragments_textstyles"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stats_rotation_img"
            android:text="50%" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you have several xml layouts, or there is one on which the differences come out?

Comment: @abbath i have several, but right now I'm trying to only get one layout to fit all different screens.

Comment: Could you post its code here? Maybe there are some improvements  which can be suggested for the exact xml source.

Comment: @abbath I will post it now. Meanwhile check the screenshots I just added

Comment: I've posted some possibilities to consider!

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [using several dimens.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html) file?

## Having different dimens but one layout

That way you could have one layout, but could define sizes of elements from different `dimens.xml`-s which are describing dp sizes separately for each size you'd like to support.
Example from the offical android page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="textview_height">25dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textview_width">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="ball_radius">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="font_size">16sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then you can use these values from the layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="@dimen/textview_height"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/textview_width"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"/>
```

If you have several dimens.xml but only one layout.xml for a page, it's easier to change them consistently.

## Design layout for tablet sizes

Also, consider checking the `smallestWidth` resource using for tablet sizes, you can handle larger screens easily width this, adding dimens.xml and/or layout to folders like `layout-sw600dp/` and `values-sw600dp/`.
[More info here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers)

Comment: I already know that! But I dont understand  what qualiferes to choose when forexample these two values are completely different but fits perfectly `1440px x 2560px 640DPI`  AND `600px x 1024px 240dpi`

Comment: And then we have theese `480px x 800px 320dpi`AND `1440px x 2560px 320DPI` Which dosn't fit at all! What is the relations where.. I don't get it..

Comment: Do you want to bundle these somehow, handling them together?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But I just want my layout to scale right on all devices and screens. I Can see that on big tablets like Nexus 9 all my views appear too small. In such case I want it to scale so they dont appear small.

Comment: Thats why I also mentioned the smallesWidth in my answer. Check that layout resource folder for Nexus 9 and tablets. The link again: [(same as in my answer): More info here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers)   Examples: sw600dp
sw720dp